# PHP - Use 'file_put_contents' in Loop

Tags: php, loops, file-put-contents

I have a script that moves through a list and if a condition is met, it echoes the line.

Now, rather than echo the line, I'd like for that line to be placed in a ***txt*** file.

Here's my code at the moment:

```
<?php
$list = file('list.txt');
foreach ($list as $x)
{
    if (condition1istrue)

    {
        echo "$x - Condition 1";
    }
    else if (condition2istrue)
    {
        echo "$x - Condition 2";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Conditions Not Met";
    }
}
?>
```

**Problem:** When I use the below code in place of the echo statement, it only adds the last line where the condition is true and deletes all other lines where the conditions were also true.

```
$file = fopen('office.txt', 'r'); 
file_put_contents('true.txt', $x);
```

Answer (score -1):

So build up the file content incrementally in a variable, then write it at the end.

```
$content = '';
foreach($foo as $bar) $content .= "Another line\r\n";
file_put_contents('file.txt', $content);
```